# C++ Object Deserialization - Where to start

Tags: c++, boost, deserialization

I have a chunk of bytes taken from a recording file that represents a C++ object. I've been given the class definition for the object. How do I convert the data(chunk of bytes) to an object?

I keep seeing references to boost but don't think I can use it since it was not used to serialize the object to begin with.

Anyone? Thanks.

Comment: Maybe this is a dumb comment I'm making, but unless you used some standard protocol used, wouldn't that depend on the compiler and/or architecture it was compiled for, as well as possibly optimizations used.

Comment: @LeifAndersen : Compiler, yes. Architecture, yes. Compiler settings, yes, but not optimization settings. I presume the OP is already aware of this, but it's worth pointing out nonetheless.

Comment: Hello, I am coming back to document my approach. Yes to all those questions and more Leif. I literally was given the directions as I stated above in a nutshell. Since I had never done this before, I thought that was all I needed. It turns out that the vendor has crappy documentation since their serialized data was never meant to be deserialized by an outsider(like me). The class definition as I stated above is a QT GUI dev base class. I had to find out exactly how the vendor was writing to the file. And I just did the opposite in reading and I linked with the QT lib version they stated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're correct -- Boost.Serialization can't help you deserialize an object it didn't serialize. You'll need to do unformatted input with `std::ifstream` (calling its `read` member function to extract byte ranges). Be sure to open the stream in binary mode.

Comment: You hit the nail on the head. This is exactly what I did. My other interesting thing about this task was that I had to write the C++ code in a DLL since the calling program is built with a C compiler. It was interesting. Thanks all for your comments. I have snippets of code that I can provide if anyone comes in here and is lost as I was a month ago.